# How can I to set a custom configuration for a snap app?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

Because `/snap/gogsgit/31/gogs/snapApp.ini` is in only read mode and the app hasn't a configuration option:

```
administrador@ubuntu:~$ sudo snap set gogsgit port="0.0.0.0:3001"
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "gogsgit" snap (snap "gogsgit" has no "configure" hook)
administrador@ubuntu:~$
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. The developer who made the snap must expose a configuration system.